# Enabling SAP mode for SAP Logon Pad in Blue Prism

Tags: scripting, blueprism, sap-gui

I followed the below steps to enable client and server side settings for SAP, hoping that this would enable the SAP mode in Blue Prisms. Even after executing the below steps and then restarting both Blue Prism and SAP logon pad, I don't see the SAP mode in blue prism. Any suggestions on what might be happening? I am still only seeing the three default modes - Win32, Accessibility and Region mode.

i. Enabling Client-Side Scripting

- Start the SAP Logon and log in to the SAP server.
- Click the 'Customize Local Layout' toolbar button (ALT+F12).
- Click Options and in the GUI Options screen select the 'Accessibility and Scripting' node
- In the ‘Accessibility’ node ensure that the ‘Use Accessibility mode’ option is enabled.
- In the 'Scripting' node ensure that the ‘Enable scripting’ option is the only option set. Notifications must be switched off to prevent popups from blocking the spy mode.
- NOTE: If the options 'Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI' check box and the 'Notify when a script opens a connection' are left checked then when you spy an element in the SAP interface you will see the message “A script is trying to attach to the GUI” every time you attempt to click on it. If you see the message “Scripting support is disabled by the user” then the ‘Enable scripting’ option has not been checked.
- Save the settings and restart the SAP GUI. The clientside settings have now been set.

ii. Enabling Server-Side Scripting

- Start the SAP Logon and log in to the SAP server.
- Run the ‘RZ11’ transaction (type ‘RZ11 ‘and click the green tick button)
- Type ‘sapgui/user_scripting’ in the Maintain Profile Parameters window.
- Click the ‘Display’ button
- Click ‘Change Value’ in the Display Profile Parameter Attributes window.
- Type ‘TRUE’ in the ‘New value’ field.
- Save the settings and log out from SAP Logon.
- Exit from the SAP Logon program (click the red cross button in the toolbar, or click the ‘X’ window button to close the window and the application). You may be prompted to save any unsaved changes, if you haven’t done so already.