# Unable to download SAP extract from SAP system - Error "Invalid GUI input data: FOCUS DATA"

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, sap-gui

Need assistance on a macro which tries to download the extract from SAP system but stops exactly in a place where it need to download. But the same problem doesn't arise when manually done.

Below are the steps which we follow in SAP system:

- In first step, Enter the TCode: ZFIS and do the below selection (Finance New GL >> Line Item Reports >> Cognos Download)
- Enter the required details and execute
- The result needs to be saved in a folder path in txt format
- The problem occurs when it reaches the yellow line code
- Manual saving doesn’t cause any trouble but when try to Run it with coding then the below error appears. Not sure why...

We tried all the possibilities (i.e. checked with our IT dept and tried to install new version of SAP system) but still we are unable to find a solution.

Lastly, I am here to see if I can find a solution for the same.

Attaching the VBA code for your reference:

```
Sub CognosUpload()

Dim SAPApplication
Dim SAPConnection
Dim SAPSession
Dim SAPGuiAuto
Dim StoringPath As Variant
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

CurYear = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "YYYY")
Period = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "MM")

MsgBox ("Please select a folder to save all the SAP Extracts.")

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        StoringPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    StoringPath = StoringPath
    If StoringPath = "" Then Exit Sub

LastSelectedRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To LastSelectedRow

If LastSelectedRow = 1 Then

SelectedCode = Cells(3, 3).Value

Else

SelectedCode = Cells(i, 3).Value

End If

With Range("PLANTCODES")
    Set Fn = .Cells.Find(What:=SelectedCode, LookIn:=xlValues)
    j = Fn.Address
End With

CodeforFilename = Range(j).Offset(0, 1).Value
   
'ChooseFilename = InputBox("Enter the desired name for the file")

If Not IsObject(SAPApplication) Then
   Set SAPGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPApplication = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPConnection) Then
   Set SAPConnection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPSession) Then
   Set SAPSession = SAPConnection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPSession, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SAPApplication, "on"
End If


    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nZFIS"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[5,3]").SetFocus
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[5,3]").caretPosition = 0
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[9,11]").SetFocus
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[9,11]").caretPosition = 0
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[16,14]").SetFocus
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[16,14]").caretPosition = 4
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").Text = "GSA"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = ""
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").caretPosition = 7
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_YEAR").Text = CurYear
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_PERIO").Text = Period
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_PERIO").SetFocus
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtP_PERIO").caretPosition = 2
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_S_BUKRS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[16]").press

    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Cells(i, 3).Copy
    
      
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[45]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = StoringPath
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = SelectedCode & ".txt"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 9
    **SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press**
    
Sheets(2).Select

InputFolder = (StoringPath & SelectedCode & ".txt")

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(InputFolder)

'Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A:I").Clear
Range("A1").Select

Call ClearTextToColumns

    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
        ActiveCell.Value = ts.ReadLine
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    
    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    'Range("A:A").Delete shift:=xlToLeft

ts.Close

Set fso = Nothing

Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("2:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlLeft
Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
If Range("A3").Value = "" Then GoTo Listmsg
MyFileName = "Congnos Download for " & CodeforFilename

sFname = StoringPath & MyFileName & ".csv"
lFnum = FreeFile
'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
Open sFname For Output As lFnum
'Loop through the rows'
    For Each rRow In Sheets("CSV Extract").UsedRange.Rows
    'Loop through the cells in the rows'
    For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
        If rCell.Column = 5 Or rCell.Column = 6 Then
            If rCell.Row = 1 Or rCell.Row = 2 Then
              sOutput = sOutput & rCell.Value & ";"
            Else
                sOutput = sOutput & Trim(Round(rCell.Value)) & ";"
            End If
        Else
            sOutput = sOutput & rCell.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next rCell
     'remove the last comma'
    sOutput = Left(sOutput, Len(sOutput) - 1)
    
    'write to the file and reinitialize the variables'
    Print #lFnum, sOutput
    sOutput = ""
 Next rRow

'Close the file'
Close lFnum

Sheets(1).Select

Listmsg:

Sheets(1).Select

Next i

Sheets(1).Select
Range("B3").Select

MsgBox "CSV file has been created for you, now you can upload the file in Cognos."


ResetSettings:


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub

Sub ClearTextToColumns()
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then Range("A1") = "XYZZY"
    Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=False, _
        OtherChar:=""
    If Range("A1") = "XYZZY" Then Range("A1") = ""
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Below are the error code:    
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear in the question where the error occurs, but you say it occurs at the last line below?  Note that the 
    wnd[1]...
means that a second window or dialog box should have opened.  I expect that it has not opened correctly, or some other unexpected event or error has occurred maybe due to the lines above this step. This can happen if the ZFIS screen/transaction has been changed?

```
SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[45]").press
SAPSession.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```

The best approach is to set a VBA breakpoint (F9) earlier in the code and step through it with (F8), and look at the SAP GUI screen with each step, to see where the script is going wrong.

Comment: This macro was created by me. On my SAP it runs perfectly without any error, but when the user runs on his system he gets this error SAP GUI bla bla.... So we approached our IT team to see if any app or crack is missing in the user's SAP but IT team could not find the cause for the error. And they came up with a solution to re-install the SAP for the user. After the installing still the user is finding the problem.

Comment: @rajkumar - what exactly is the error? - it is not clear above.  Common issues are that scripting is not enabled for the user (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073813/enabling-sap-mode-for-sap-logon-pad-in-blue-prism), or their rights are different to yours (run /nSU53 to display authorisation errors).  You can still step through the VB code on their PC, as I suggest above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this bug still exists after all these years... And I spent hours trying to fix it and found that if I `SetFocus` on the file name field, the bug doesn't happen.

Try adding this command line right before you push the button to save the file:

```
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
```

The exact command may differ based on User/Transaction, but this one worked for me and other people.